# How to translate "city distance signs"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How to translate in German:

> There aren't many of these city distance signs around.

Example:

> London 10000km
>   Singapore 2000km

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a fixed term for them.
So instead of using a bureaucratic word like *Distanzanzeiger* or some clumsy noun creation, I'd choose a description.

> Es gibt in dieser Gegend nicht viele von diesen Schildern, die die Entfernung zu internationalen Großstädten anzeigen.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest German term i know for this is

> Schilder, die die Entfernung zu Weltstädten zeigen

or for the entire pole with many such sings:

> Schilderbaum, der die Entfernung zu Weltstädten zeigt

I cannot deny that this is a relative clause and that therefore some people may struggle with accepting this as a word. (Although when we start into debating word boundaries I might even win that debate.)

Now, for the sake of experimenting, we could try to create one-word-solutions:

> Weltstadtentfernungsschild

This would be a working solution, not too long, and unambiguously intelligible.

More beautiful, but perhaps not that practical as not fully self-explanatory would be:

> Weltstadtweiser

This impresses through compendiousness and an inner alliteration.

It could be used for the single sign as well as for the entire contraption (pole and multiple signs).

The problem with both of them is that probably the first place where these words have ever been published is... here.

**Later thoughts...**

I am developing the feeling that perhaps

> Entfernungstafeln

might be in use somehow, although it is clearly totally unspecific and could mean a plethora of other things, too.

Comment: How about *Überallhinweiser*?

Comment: Also, *Südpolweiser* does match, because it's the only sort of *Wegweiser* that has the south pole on it.

Comment: "Weltstadtentfernungsschild: This would be (...) unambiguously intelligible." - okay, aber rein vom Begriff her ist mir jetzt noch nicht klar, ob so ein Schild schon im Voraus aufgestellt wird oder erst, während an der Stelle gerade eine Weltstadt entfernt wird ;)