# Gibt es ein Wort für jene horizontalen Tafeln, die die Richtung zu fernen Landschaftspunkten zeigen?

Tags: single-word-request

Auf vielen Aussichtspunkten (Kirchtürmen, Rathauskuppeln, Aussichtstürmen, Berggipfeln) findet man horizontal montierte Metalltafeln mit eingravierter Abbildung des Horizonts, wichtigen Landschaftspunkten darauf - etwa am Horizont sichtbaren Berggipfeln - Richtungspfeilen sowie manchmal auch Entfernungsangaben.

Gibt es einen halbwegs etablierten Begriff für diese Tafeln?

Der normale Wanderer benutzt diese Tafeln gern, benennt sie aber nicht. Er hat kein Wort für sie. Jedoch könnte ich  mir vorstellen, dass im Kreise von Lokalbehörden, ihren Tourismusabteilungen, und zulieferenden Betrieben der metallverarbeitenden Industrie für diese Tafeln durchaus ein Wort im Schwange ist. Irgendwie muss das Ding ja z.B. in Ausschreibungstexten und Lieferverträgen benannt werden.

Wenn so ein Word nicht aufspürbar ist, würden auch Vorschläge für Neuprägungen helfen.

Verwandte Frage: [How to translate in German City distance signs"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50580/how-to-translate-in-german-city-distance-signs)

Comment: Der *gemeine* Wanderer :D

Comment: @Philipp  Otto Normalwanderer? Max Musterwanderer?

Comment: Oder in der weiblichen Form: Wanda Musterwanderin? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diese Tafeln werden üblicherweise als

> Panoramatafel

bezeichnet. Eine Suche nach dem Begriff, insbesondere eine Bildersuche, liefert viele Beispiele, die der Beschreibung in der Frage entsprechen.

Comment: (+1) An die Dinger habe ich gar nicht gedacht. Ich hatte was völlig anderes im Sinn.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn ich es richtig verstanden habe, suchst du nach dem Begriff [Touristische Unterrichtungstafel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touristische_Unterrichtungstafel).

Comment: Nein, so etwas meinte ich nicht. Deine Bilder zeigen ja senkrecht (!) stehende Wegweiser zu Sehenswürdigkeiten. Ich meinte waagrecht an Aussichtspunkten montierte Tafeln, die den Horizont abbilden (meistens im Winkel von 180 Grad) und auf vielerlei Landmarken hinweisen.